# Expo App is stuck on splash screen for IOS

Tags: ios, react-native, expo

I have a react-native built with Expo that is already on the Google play store, Runs perfectly well in the Expo Go app both on IOS and Android.

After pushing the same app to my Apple developer account and testing with TestFlight, it does not go past the splash screen. Below is my package.json file

```
{
  "main": "node_modules/expo/AppEntry.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "expo start",
    "android": "expo start --android",
    "ios": "expo start --ios",
    "web": "expo start --web",
    "eject": "expo eject"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@eva-design/eva": "^2.1.1",
    "@react-native-async-storage/async-storage": "~1.17.3",
    "@react-native-community/datetimepicker": "6.1.2",
    "@react-native-community/masked-view": "0.1.10",
    "@react-navigation/bottom-tabs": "^6.0.4",
    "@react-navigation/drawer": "^6.1.3",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^6.0.2",
    "@react-navigation/stack": "^5.14.5",
    "@ui-kitten/components": "^5.1.1",
    "@ui-kitten/eva-icons": "^5.1.1",
    "apisauce": "^2.1.1",
    "expo": "^45.0.0",
    "expo-cli": "^6.0.1",
    "expo-status-bar": "~1.3.0",
    "expo-updates": "~0.13.3",
    "react": "17.0.2",
    "react-dom": "17.0.2",
    "react-native": "0.68.2",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "~2.2.1",
    "react-native-modal-datetime-picker": "^11.0.0",
    "react-native-reanimated": "~2.8.0",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "4.2.4",
    "react-native-safe-area-view": "^1.1.1",
    "react-native-screens": "~3.11.1",
    "react-native-svg": "12.3.0",
    "react-native-web": "0.17.7"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.12.9"
  },
  "private": true
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After much troubleshooting, the following steps helped to resolve the issue:

1. Upgraded NodeJS.
2. Deleted node_modules folder.
3. Ran `yarn install`

I did all these then rebuilt the app, tested it on Testflight, and it worked as expected.